# Remove brackets from postgres table column but keep words inside them

Tags: database, postgresql, regexp-replace

I have a title column which contains some words within brackets. I would like to remove the brackets but keep the words which are currently inside them by using regexp_replace.
I tried this but it didn't seem to work. There is still brackets in the column.

```
UPDATE test_table SET title = regexp_replace(title, '()', '', 'g');
```

Comment: () is valid regex syntax. Instead, try '(|)'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not tested, but assuming that this is regular regex syntax.

```
UPDATE test_table SET title = regexp_replace(title, '\(|\)', '', 'g');
```

or

```
UPDATE test_table SET title = regexp_replace(title, '[()]', '', 'g');
```

Putting the () into `[]` means to look for each single character. Using the `|` means "or", but you need to `\` escape the () in that case.

Comment: Nice one, good answer I used the 2nd option, worked perfectly.

Answer (score 5):

You could also use the BTRIM function for this. Example:

```
BTRIM(title,'[]') as "title"
```

Cheers!